# How to set 'hardwareBackPress' to another Stack

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native, addeventlistener

[image]

```
//TermsPage.tsx
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'BottomTabNav',
    params:{showTerms:false}
  }),
  ],
});
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',()=>{
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
      return true
    })
  }
```

How to set 'hardwareBackPress' eventListenner to navigate to another StackNavigator. If I set like above. This backpress work in all Pages. I want to set this listener only for TermsPage. And set this listener to navigate to another StackNavigator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve this problem with function `pop()`.
In the page, where I want to go another stack I added

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'BottomTabNav',
    params:{showTerms:false}
  }),
  ],
});
```

```
handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
    return true;
  }
```

And in another pages

````
handleBackButtonClick() {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.props.navigation.pop();
    return true;
  }
``` And voila
````

Answer (score -1):

you can use this example, here we bind this method in Constructer and also call this function whenever the screen is rendering back

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
        };

      }
      componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener(
          'hardwareBackPress',
          this.handleBackButtonClick,
        );
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener(
          'hardwareBackPress',
          this.handleBackButtonClick,
        );
      }
      handleBackButtonClick() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('name of page where you want to nav');
        return true;
      }
```

From where you don't want to go back use this..

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }
  handleBackButton() {
    return true;
  }
```

It will not let you go back from the page where you are, please import BackHandler from react-native.
hope it helps, feel free for Doubts.

Comment: I did it like your code, but there, when I click back button in another screen of this stack, I'm again go to back to those stack that I wrote. That's my problem